# Почему операция "инкремент" не работает с массивом?

Tags: php

Простейший пример :

```
$array = [1, 2, 3];
$result = $array[0]++; // Никаких ошибок код не выдаёт
echo "<p> $result"; // В переменной 1 а не 2.
```

Я ожидал получить другой результат. Что это баг, или так надо ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо сделать так:

```
$result = ++$array[0];
```

**Подробнее:**

Строка: `$result = $array[0]++;` делает 2 действия:

1) $result = $array[0];

2) $array[0]++;

Это связанно с принципом работы инкремента. Наглядно можно убедиться на этом примере:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3];
$link = &$array[0];
$result = $link++;
var_dump($result, $link);
```

В документации `PHP` [написано](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.increment.php):

> **++$a**  -   Увеличивает $a на единицу, затем возвращает значение $a.
>
> **$a++**  -   Возвращает значение $a, затем увеличивает $a на единицу.